# Webrat has unexpected outcome when 'if' statement is used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, webrat

I have been using webrat with my rails 3.0.7 project and have been trying to write a test that uses regular expressions.  It should fail, yet the if statement seems to corrupt the outcome.

```
    it "should have 'microposts' if 0 posted" do
      visit root_path
      response.should have_selector('span.microposts') do |span|
        if span =~ /\d/
          span.should contain('hello')
        end
      end
    end
```

The test is trying to confirm that the test, yet it still succeeds when an 'if' statement is used.  It is trying to match the content '0 microposts'.

When I use these lines in replacement of the 'if' statement:

```
   response.should have_selector('span.microposts') do |counter|
     counter.should contain(/hello/)
   end
```

I get the test to finally fail like it is supposed to, but then I don't get to verify the number in front of the content inside of the span like I was trying to above.

Does webrat not hand if statements well, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing an `end` but I don't see how that wouldn't bomb.

```
it "should have 'microposts' if 0 posted" do
  visit root_path
  response.should have_selector('span.microposts') do |span|
    if span =~ /\d/
      span.should contain('hello')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I actually did have that end in my code, but forgot to include it here.  Just updated the question.  Do you think that webrat may not like to go more than 1 layer deep?

Comment: How about `span.should span =~ /\d/ && contain('hello')`?